# onchange event with bootstrap4xpages control

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

Hello I need to use **Select2 enhanced Combo box:** but seem that the event handler doesn't work.
Can someone confirm that?
I have select the event from a combo....but nothign partial update are executed

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this [blogger](http://xcellerant.net/2013/12/11/triggering-partial-refresh-on-change-select2/) seem work